# How to fix the send transaction Implicit contract error on Tezos

Tags: php, node.js

How to Fix the Implicit contract error to send Transaction On Tezos for Nodejs and PHP

> Node error :Command failed : Empty implicit contract  Php Error :
>   [{"kind":"branch","id":"proto.004-Pt24m4xi.implicit.empty_implicit_contract","implicit":"tz1.........................."}]

Comment: Is there any code you can share around this error?  As it stands, this question is going to be near impossible to answer with just a print of the error.

Comment: PHP Code:
curl -X POST  http://localhost:6000/chains/main/blocks/head/helpers/preapply/operations -H Content-Type: application/json -d '[{ \"protocol\":\"Pt24m4xiPbLDhVgVfABUjirbmda3yohdN82Sp9FeuAXJ4eV9otd\",\"branch\":\"Branchhash\",\"contents\":[{\"kind\":\"transaction\",\"amount\":\"1\",\"source\":\"fromaddress\",\"destination\":\"toaddress\",\"storage_limit\":\"0\",\"gas_limit\":\"10500\",\"fee\":\"1\",\"counter\":\"1\"}],\"signature\":\"signaturehash\" }]'

Comment: Termainal Command:

./tezos-client -addr 127.0.0.1 --port 6000 rpc post /chains/main/blocks/head/helpers/preapply/operations with  '[{ "protocol": "Pt24m4xiPbLDhVgVfABUjirbmda3yohdN82Sp9FeuAXJ4eV9otd","branch":"Branchhash","contents":[{ "kind": "transaction", "amount": "1", "source": "fromaddress","destination": "toaddress","storage_limit": "0","gas_limit": "10500","fee": "1","counter": "1"}],"signature":"signaturehash"}]'

Comment: Add it to the question with some good formatting

Comment: i tried the send amount one tezos address to another address on tezos, I got the Error Implicit contract error .I  had  used the below curl command 

curl -X POST localhost:6000/chains/main/blocks/head/helpers/preapply/… -H Content-Type: application/json -d '[{ \"protocol\":\"Pt24m4xiPbLDhVgVfABUjirbmda3yohdN82Sp9FeuAXJ4eV9otd\",\"branch\":\"Branchhash\",\"contents\":[{\"kind\":\"transaction\",\"amount\":\"1\",\"source\":\"fromaddress\",\"destination\":\"toaddress\",\"storage_limit\":\"0\",\"gas_limit\":\"10500\",\"fee\":\"1\",\"counter\":\"1\"}],\"signature\":\"signaturehash\" }]

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue while working with the [eztz](https://github.com/TezTech/eztz) library of tezos on Node JS. I suggest you going through the following points:

1. Changing the host of your cURL request to https://rpc.tezrpc.me if you're publishing on mainnet and this https://rpcalpha.tzbeta.net if you're publishing on Testnet (or Babylonnet, previously Alphanet).
2. I also suggest changing your ***fee*** value to **1275** and ***storage_limit*** to **300** in case changing the host doesn't help alone.
3. I have also noticed that you're passong a value of **1** in the ***amount*** field, I hope you know that the value in this field is in Micro-Tez or μꜩ. Which means that the value here is divided by 10 ^ -6. So I suggest making changes accordingly, like if you wish to send 1 Tezos, write ***amount: 1000000***.
4. Make sure that the counter value you pass in the ***counter*** field is 1 more than what you get from the /chains/main/blocks/head/context/contracts/tz1........................../counter API

Please let me know if any of this worked out for you, if not, feel free to revert :)